# Find same dictionary by value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have dictionary like below

```
dict1 = {'a':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'b':{'a':30, 'b':40}, 'c':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'd':{'a':30, 'b':40}}
```

Then in following dictionary two dictionaries are same, so expected result will be like below

```
result = [['a','c'],['b','d']]
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one pair of nested dictionaries with identical values?

Comment: Why did you change the expected output so drastically?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience,

Comment: Do you expect output to be ordered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> seen = {}
>>> dict1 = {'a':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'b':{'a':30, 'b':40}, 'c':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'd':{'a':30, 'b':40}}
>>> for k in dict1:
        fs = frozenset(dict1[k].items())
        seen.setdefault(fs, []).append(k)


>>> seen.values() # note: unordered
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
```

If order is needed:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dict1 = {'a':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'b':{'a':30, 'b':40}, 'c':{'a':20, 'b':30}, 'd':{'a':30, 'b':40}}
>>> seen = OrderedDict()
>>> for k in sorted(dict1):
        fs = frozenset(dict1[k].items())
        seen.setdefault(fs, []).append(k)


>>> seen.values()
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
```

**Note:** This code is currently cross-compatible on Python 2/3. On Python 2 you can make it more efficient by using `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`

Answer (score 0):

A quick one: 1st get different values, then list comprehension.

```
>>> values = []
>>> for k in dict1:
    if dict1[k] not in values:
        values.append(dict1[k])


>>> values
[{'a': 20, 'b': 30}, {'a': 30, 'b': 40}]
>>> [[k for k in dict1 if dict1[k] == v] for v in values]
[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
```